# IE not triggering jQuery Ajax success when set dataType script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
      url: '/comment_rewards/' + comment_reward_id + '/pay.js',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {channel: reward_style, reward_num: reward_num},
      dataType: "script",
      cache: true
    })
    .done(function() {
      console.log("success");
      reward.closeShade()
      reward.infoPrompt("支付成功！", "success")
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
      console.log("complete");
    });
```

Set dataType to any other available response type is working and console"success",but response js file is not working.
in Firefox, Webkit (Safari,Chrome) and it works.
in IE console "error"
any ideas?

Comment: What's the console error you're getting?

Comment: no console error message  only handle the fail function

Comment: So the fail function is being called? Add a param to the function, and log that. E.g. `fail(function(a,b,c) { console.log('error',a,b,c); })`

Comment: If it's failing then there's an error, as @evolutionxbox says add logging to find out what the error is.

Comment: console syntaxerror,   response js  is erb file with ruby sync， is this reason?

Answer (score 1):

IE might not be setting by default the X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest header. Set it up manually by adding it in the Ajax call with the usual headers property.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/comment_rewards/' + comment_reward_id + '/pay.js',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {channel: reward_style, reward_num: reward_num},
  headers:{
      X-Requested-With: "XMLHttpRequest"
  }
  dataType: "script",
  cache: true
})
```

Check the online documentation of $ajax to check for sure how to set a header.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/